# Spring, showing an error occurred view on exception or 404

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="core/*")
public class CoreController {

    public static String exceptionOccurredView = "/core/exceptionOccurred";

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public ModelAndView exceptionOccurred(Throwable exception, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName ( exceptionOccurredView );
        mv.addObject   ( "requestedUrl", Core.getCurrentUrlWithParams() );
        mv.addObject   ( "exception", exception );

        System.out.println( "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + Core.getCurrentUrlWithParams() );
        return mv;
    }   

    @RequestMapping
    public void test0(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException();
    } 

}
```

which works fine for all exeptions occuring under core url.

if I go to url

**localhost:8080/core/test0**

the error page is shown. Also if I go to:

**localhost:8080/core/actionDoesNotExist**

but if I use:

**localhost:8080/controllerDoesNotExist/test0**

The error does not get shown, since the annotation @ExceptionHandler is valid only per controller.

So how can you achieve a global, non-controller attached exception/error handler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use some implementation of `HandlerExceptionResolver`.

For example to use `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver, put this in your context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
      <map>
         <entry key="IOException" value="io-error" />
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="default-error"/>
</bean>
```

That way you define a global mapping from exceptions to error pages. If you need some more complicated error handling, implement your own resolver.

Comment: Is it possible not to render a view, but redirect to a controller/action for some prepropccessing?

Comment: I am guessing you have to create your own implementation of HandlerExceptionResolver.. thanks!

Comment: I was to quick to accept your answer, after testing it, the same result was achieved :(

Comment: That's because in `localhost:8080/controllerDoesNotExist/test0` case it doesn't find mapping for the request. The request doesn't even get to be processed by any controller. The simplest way to handle that is to define a 404 error page.

Comment: You can also define a catch-all controller that maps `"/"`  to it's only method method, and that method throws the exception you need.

Comment: @Hamidam this link gives you a nice example of handling the generic exceptions http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/. Its same as soulcheck said. You need to have your own exception defined and map that exception to the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver or you can generically give Throwable.

Comment: @raddykrish the own handler thingy ive already tried. i believe the only way is to define a 404 in web.xml...